# Sharepoint - Load a form's view based on user

Tags: forms, sharepoint-2010, filter, load, infopath2010

I am using a data connection list to load desired views in an InfoPath form on SharePoint.  I have a permission list with 2 columns: usernames and control group.  My form on the main list loads a specific view based on what the username and group are of the permission list.  You have to filter out the group based on the form's username() function to match the username column and set that as a condition to (on form load) change it to a specific view.

All this works, but the problem comes in when you have a user with multiple control groups.  The filter only returns the first instance it finds.  I can't think of a way to fix this.  Maybe load the other list as a repeating table into the form, but then how would I reference that table in the conditions of a form load rule? Or is there a way to get a field filter to look past the first item it finds?

Update: I forgot to mention that I have to use a field to hold your filtered username:id:group aka group[title=username()] and then use that in the form load conditions.  I think this is where the problem is, as this filter is what doesn't store all instances of the users id from the control list, but only the first.

SharePoint 2010 with forms created in InfoPath 2010

Answer (score 0):

Are you querying the data in from info path or using visual studio, if you are querying in info path check the condition as Display name matches the username() and the query the data

Comment: I am doing it all in InfoPath 2010. I don't understand. It automatically queries the secondary list in the condition because it uses fields from that list.  Where are you saying to have it query?  I know you can create a second action to force a query, but I don't see how this would help if it was in a separate rule.

Comment: I'm thinking the way to solve this would be to have a repeating field that holds all the info from the control list in the form, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Ok you can use preceding:sibiling finction in the rules , in the expression column